# Will Godox X series triggers fire from the center pin?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, godox

Can I fire a Godox X-series trigger from a generic hotshoe with only a center pin?

For example, if I have a Nikon compatible Godox X2 trigger mounted on a Pentax K1000 hot shoe, will the trigger still transmit and fire to X-series compatible Godox studio strobes (in non-TTL mode of course)?

Or will the absence of Nikon specific pins prevent the Nikon compatible X2 trigger from firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I accept a broad definition of “trigger,” then the X series compatible Godox manual flashes (such as the TT600) can fit the requirement without work arounds. They are capable of operating in master mode.

The Godox X1T series triggers can be set to “single pin mode” using the custom function menu. The trigger will then ignore signals on the other proprietary pins. The Neewer N1T triggers are identical to the X1 and compatible with the Godox X series wireless system. The Flashpoint R2T series triggers are also the same.

In addition all the Godox X series triggers (X1, X-Pro, X2) can be fired by cable using PC, 2.5mm, 3.5mm ports respectively. Not quite the same as center pin, but broadens the possible systems to which the flashes can be connected. E.g film cameras with a pc socket.

Finally the Godox V850 is similar to the TT600 but has a Lithium Rechargeable Battery.

Answer (score 1):

It will work. If it fits in the hotshoe and the hotshoe has a center pin it can fire.

The flash trigger may get confused if it gets signals from any other pin than the center pin. The X1T has a single pin mode to prevent it from getting confused by signals on other pins:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pnrp6XnPMmg

The Xpro does not have a single pin mode, if there are other pins on the camera you may have to use Scotch tape to prevent signals from reaching the flash:
https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4357114
(See reaction from Kli)

This video shows how it can work on an old film camera:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyVVKu2RzNo

Comment: The Godox trigger single pin mode is only for the output on the passthrough hotshoe, which is why the Xpro doesn't have it (it doesn't have a passthrough hotshoe). The X1T trigger (et-all) will still see other TTL communications, such as shutter speed for switching into HSS, even in single pin mode. Miscommunication (wrong brand/wrong pin) and disabling HSS *may* require taping over the other pins. The main key is both trigger and flash being in manual mode.

Comment: @StevenKersting: Thanks for the information. It does contradict some of the information I found elsewhere and I am not sure what is correct. I will just leave it as a comment for now. If I find out more I will change the answer.

Comment: I tested center pin mode of the X1T extensively trying to get my remote Godox flashes (AD200/360) to fire in tail sync rather than HSS. The only way it was possible was to tape off the TTL communication pins between the camera and trigger.